# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT when trying to use the NuxtJS api

Tags: javascript, typescript, nuxt.js, vercel, servermiddleware

I am using NuxtJS 2, I deployed my app on Vercel and everything has been working fine. The things changed when I decided to add serverMiddleware, I created a `api` folder, I added the following to the nuxt.config.js file:

```
serverMiddleware: [{
  path: '/api',
  handler: '~/api/newsletter.ts'
}],
```

**And everything works just fine locally. As expected.** I released it to my preview environment, added the corresponding environment variables, but when I try to do an api call I get the following error: **POST http://localhost:3000/api/subscribe net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT** in the release environment.

I am aware it says local host. I tried adding a vercel.json with the corresponding configuration, but it won't work in Vercel. How do I get to use api call without it being denied by the client?

P.S: This is my client side code:

```
<script>
(...)
    async subscribe () {
      this.form.sending = true;
      this.form.errors.push('Sending...');

      try {
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
        const response = await this.$axios.$post('/api/subscribe', { email: this.form.email });
        this.form.success = true;
        this.resetFormEmail();
        this.form.errors.push('Thanks for subscribing!');
      } catch (error) {
        this.form.errors.push(`${error.response.data.title}`);
      } finally {
        this.closeFormStatus();
        this.form.sending = false;
      }
    }
(...)
```

Comment: What does your client-side code look like where you're making the request?

Comment: You can check it out now

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure your app is working well on your local, then it might be cors issue.
Try this: https://vercel.com/guides/how-to-enable-cors

Comment: I tried configuring Cors manually with Express, or Axios, and neither of them are working.  I think the issue is related to it though.